# Spring MVC: With SimpleMappingExceptionResolver, what parameters are passed to the view

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I've implemented SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.

I want to embed the exception text in an HTML comment, how can I access the exception from the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception object is passed to the view as variable: exception

Logical!